# Fill textarea value from url parmeter then write value to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, url-parameters

i have textarea & iframe with `src='about:blank'` , the textarea will be filld with alittle HTML [1 or 2 tags to preview] that obtained from url parameter "preview" for example [before decoding url]

```
http://example.com/?preview=<h1>this-is-heading-line</h1><p>and-this-is-paragraph</p>
```

**Then** [in the same order] write textarea's value to iframe using

```
var textarea_value = document.getElementById('mytextarea').value  
document.getElementById('preview').contentDocument.write(textarea_value);
```

when the page is fully loaded using javascript .. how to do that in the same order ? what can i use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` or `$(window).ready` ?

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the Q is what the full code must i use to do that in the same order ? what can i use window.onload or $(document).ready $(window).ready

Comment: $(window).ready? or you mean $(window).load?

Comment: sorry i mean $(window).load not $(winow).ready

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explain between the document ready and window onload, you may then see which one is more suitable in your case.

**$(document).ready**

This code is written when we execute our code when DOM is ready except images. 
i.e If our web page has images then it will not wait for loading of images  and call and in one page we can apply many document.ready and it call one by one as coming sequence.we call document.ready in many ways like below and they have same functionality and it is jQuery specific event.

**$(window).load**

And if we talk about $(window).load then it is work when all DOM is ready including images so it is useful when on document load we want to work with images (calculation of image dimensions) and it is also jQuery specific event.If our web page has  images then  it will wait for loading of images  and then it  call

**window.onload**

The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while above two are specific to jQuery . This is also same functionality like $(window).load but  window.onload is the built-in JavaScript event.The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded.like if we take a example of image and call onload event in image tag then it will call when image will load .generally we use it in body tag.

ref: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/document-ready-vs-window-load-vs-window-onload

Comment: :) if this solved your problem, please accept my answer, so people can look into this solution in the future.

Comment: please let me try .. it's non-direct answer